# Property 'customerCode' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Tags: typescript, react-native

Hey guys i'm getting this error from typescript: `Property does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'`
i export a default interface called `iCustomer` which i can use all over my project. But now i imported it on `CustomerViewList` as i was lazy to repeat myself when typing out the props.

after that i want to import the view and use it on my flat list and now kinda getting this error.

[image]

Comment: It's telling you that CustomerViewList doesn't have a prop called "customerCode". It looks like you've defined two props, `customer` and `onPress`

Comment: You should be able to write `renderItem={({item}) => <CustomerViewList customer={item} onPress={onPress} /> }`

Comment: Could you rewrite a proper answer so that I can accept it? it works.

Comment: Moved it over for posterity :+1:

Comment: I faced similar error in VSCode, I realized I had opened files with changes that I didn't save. After saving them, this error either goes away or you get a clearer error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is telling you that CustomerViewList doesn't have a prop called "customerCode". It looks like you've defined two props, `customer` and `onPress`.

You should be able to write
`renderItem={({item}) => <CustomerViewList customer={item} onPress={onPress} /> }`